# Navigate to object property value shorthand definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

**JS module example**:

```
const foo = params => {}
const bar = params => {}

const someStructure = {
  foo, // here its definition is navigable!!!
}

module.exports = {
  foo, // can't navigate to the definition
  bar: bar, // can navigate to the definition
}
```

Here `bar` definition is navigable with `CTRL+click` in `VSCode`, whereas `foo` is not.

I think this used to work sometimes ago, but I'm not sure.

**Update**

The object property value is NOT navigable from `exports` object, but it is navigable from another object inside the module!

VSCode version `1.52.1` (Linux)

Comment: Seems working fine

Comment: Is it possible that a plugin causes this? It works fine for me.

Comment: @sandrooco I've tried to disable all extensions and to reset global and workspace settings - hasn't helped.